# How can i get the Process used to open a file in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am trying to open different files with their associated applications like this:

```
                ProcessPath = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Tulips.jpg";
                ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                processStartInfo.FileName = ProcessPath;
                processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(ProcessPath);

                process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
                process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                process.Exited += Process_Exited;
                process.Start();
```

Please can you help me get hold of the Process object that represents the application opened because after the call to process.Start(); most of the fields inside process have threw exceptions.

Thanks.

Comment: That is the process, though it isn't necessarily ready for interaction yet (or anymore - there's no guarantee that asking the shell to open a file will result in a new process; think all Excel files being opened in one instance of Excel, for example). What are you trying to do?

Comment: Mainly open image file's or PDF's with their default applications. So the code i posted above will open up one of the default windows images in Windows photo viewer but the process which started it will be useless as far as i can see.

Comment: the process may not have done anything by the time you're looking  however, what you're doing is equivelent to "start my.jpg" rather than launching an app with your jpg for opening, so process.WaitForInputIdle(); wont help as the process probably has terminated because the process then spawned the actual app

Comment: I assumed that might be happening, but id like to know how i can get the ID or name of the process it spawns, any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can, really. As I said, it doesn't even have to be a process - associations aren't necessarily "launch this exe with these arguments", there's also DLL's and DDL's and others. There's no guarantee that a process is launched at all, and if it is launched, how long it survives and what it does. What do you want to do with the launched process (if there is one, and it isn't subject to any of the problems already mentioned)? What are you trying to do *from the user's perspective*? Wait for the application to be closed? How would that work on Windows 8+ for the non-desktop apps?

Comment: It is for Windows 7 and i have a full screen application which needs to open certain files with their associated application in front of my app but the standard user is not allowed to minimize or close my application (or see the taskbar for that matter) so i keep hold of the process's handle and create my own taskbar which uses windows api calls to control the opened app. So in essence i just need the handle of any application i open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution:

using the Windows API function

```
        [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    static extern int FindExecutable(string file, string directory, [Out] StringBuilder lpResult);
```

to return the associated application path for a given file. I can then use the original code i posted to execute that associated application with the original file passed through as an argument!